# Modify python file which was installed using pip inside an Docker image

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, docker, pip

I installed a python module called requests-aws4auth in docker using `RUN pip install requests-aws4auth`

Now I want to modify it by going into `cd /opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_aws4auth/` and commenting a line in `aws4auth.py` file. I already installed vim while building the docker.

Is it possible to do this while building the dockerfile? If yes, then can some one help me out.

I could do it by using `sudo docker run -i -t image_name /bin/bash` and modifying the file, but this will create a container. Now, is there any way to push the container back to the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Add some sed command that comments the line in the file after `pip install` command in dockerfile something like this -

   `RUN pip install requests-aws4auth
   RUN sed -e '/BBB/ s/^#*/#/' -i file #some logic to comment the line`

   Build the docker image and use it.
2. If option-1 didn't seems to help try committing the container.
   `docker run` the container do `docker exec` and comment the line in file. Now commit the container `docker commit <conatainer-id> <some custom image name>` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/
   Now use this custom image.